# How to obtain desired result using SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, optimization

I have the following sql relation named **recordbase**

+----+----------+----------+
|  **id**  |  **views**  |  **name**  |
+----+----------+----------+
|   1  |   120     |   abcd   |
+----+----------+----------+
|   2  |   200     |   cdef    |
+----+----------+----------+
|   3  |   200     |   efgh    |
+----+----------+----------+
|   4  |   100     |   ghmk  |
+----+----------+----------+

Now i want to display the results in descending order of **views**. I used the following query to get the entry with max views:

`SELECT name FROM recordbase WHERE views IN (SELECT max(views) FROM recordbase);`

After processing this SQL query (in PHP), the **id** of entry with max views is saved in variable `$currentid` and its views (i.e. the maximum views) is stored in `$temp`. So that to obtain further descending order I can loop the following block:

`SELECT name FROM recordbase WHERE views IN (SELECT max(views) FROM recordbase WHERE views < '$temp')
$temp = views returned by above query`

But this creates problem, as if there are two entries with same `views` and are maximum, for example here entries 2 and 3 have same values of `views` and are max, then the output will include the following results:

> cdef
>   abcd
>   ghmk

While I am in need of the below output:

> cdef
>   efgh
>   abcd
>   ghmk

Is there any pre-defined function which can resolve the issue of sorting values with same value.?
Or i am doing it all wrong and there is some better way?

Comment: Why don't you use `ORDER BY`? Its simple `SELECT name FROM recordbase ORDER BY views desc`

Comment: I am new to SQL, will surely try

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? They are not the same thing, and the syntax is not always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM recordbase order by views desc,name asc;
```